# Can't figure out what's wrong with my flask app when porting it from localhost

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask, pythonanywhere

#### OVERVIEW

Hi, I have a Flask app that works on my localhost but not in pythonanywhere. My app basically does the following:

1. User fills out HTML form, hits submit
2. Script in HTML form uses jQuery $ajax to post to my flask app on sumbit
3. Flask app processes the data and sends it back to be displayed as HTML

Here are some things that I think might be wrong with my app when moving it to pythonanywhere:

1. urllib.requests might not be included in pythonanaywhere, I know urllib is included but I'm not sure if urllib.requests is different or just a part of urllib
2. On my localhost, my URL for $ajax was 'http:// 127.0.0.1:5000/ebaycode/', I couldnt find any info on what youre supposed to change this to after hours of looking so I tried 'http:// mander39.pythonanywhere.com/ebaycode/' which might be wrong
3. I have no idea what @app.route does and maybe this is messed up when moving to pythonanywhere

#### HTML CODE

```
<script>
        $('#form').on('submit', function(e){
            #random css changes with jQuery i.e. $('.box').css( "display","none")
            #conditionals based on form data i.e. if ($('.checkbox').is(":checked"))
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://mander39.pythonanywhere.com/ebaycode/',
                data: {'product': product, 'sold': sold, 'cond': cond},
                method: 'POST',
                success: function(data) {
                    #using $('#id').html to show my data output on my site
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

#### FLASK APP

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
from statistics import mean 
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/ebaycode/', methods=['POST'])
def ebaycode():
    prod = str(request.form.get('product', 0))
    sold = str(request.form.get('sold', 0))
    cond = str(request.form.get('cond', 0))
    #whole bunch of other code 
    data = {'ebaycode': ebaycode,'lengthOne': lengthOne,'maxOne': maxOne,
            'minOne': minOne,'avgOne': avgOne,'medOne': medOne, 'lengthTwo': lengthTwo,
            'maxTwo':maxTwo, 'minTwo':minTwo,'avgTwo': avgTwo,'medTwo': medTwo, 'url': tac
            }
    data = jsonify(data)
    return data

def reject_outliers(data, m = 3.):
    #method called in ebaycode()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I wish I had a command prompt to show what my app is doing but bash and python cmd from pythonanywhere dont show anything. Thanks a bunch for the help, I really need it.

Comment: Some things that might help you: Have you checked the log files? These can be accessed in your pythonanywhere account. What are the last entries in the access, error and server log? How have you set up the WSGI file? And what exactly is the problem you face?

Comment: With `@app.route()` you define different endpoints for your app. E.g. if you make a request to `your_base_url/` than `return render_template('index.html')` is executed.